# GnuWin (GSL) on Windows and Geany

Tags: c, windows, gsl, geany

I want to use GSL on a Windows 11 system using Geany as IDE for coding in C.

I installed GnuWin directly on the C-drive and added C:\GnuWin\bin in PATH, but still I cannot get Geany to compile.

I'm no computer scientist, so the help files and documentation given don't help me as I'm not familiar with a lot of the terminology.

Any help, preferably step-by-step instructions on how to get my system and Geany set up to be able to use GSL, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install a compiler? Can you explain what you're attempting and the actual problem you're having in greater detail?

Comment: If you're not a computer scientist, maybe you should avoid WSL.
Use a native windows toolchain like MinGW-w64 (you can get it from https://winlibs.com/). There are other IDEs available on Windows like Code::Blocks or VSCode.

Comment: I have installed MinGW-w64 and am running that using Geany without issues.  The use is straightforward.  How to use GNUWin on it, apparently is a different matter.  Anyway, I'm currently taking another route by programming a "false position"-method myself.